# Should I edit a tpl file from module? (Prestashop)

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm developing a module that links 2 products (in the example a white t-shirt and a black t-shirt), so in the product page instead of 1 color, there are both colors, like this:

[image]

In order to do that I modified the product-variants.tpl file like this:

```
<input {if $group_attribute.url != ""} onclick="location.href='{$group_attribute.url}'"{/if} class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
```

Basically adding an onclick if the color is the one of the other product (in this case it would be added on the withe one)

And it works perfectly (of course I modified the controller, and a few more things, but that's not the problem).

My problem is that if I upload the module to the prestashop addons so everyone can download, the tpl file won't be modified, how can I modify that?

Comment: Here is something about tpl modify for modules: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/overriding-modules/

Comment: I think that's the opposite of what I want. That documentation is explaining how to change a module tpl in your theme, I want to change a theme tpl from my module.

Comment: @sefean you should include documentation in your module to replace product-variants.tpl file to yours file. Write a clean and good documentation for this.

Comment: @Sachin yeah that's what I'm gonna do, because it doesn't seem to be any other good way of doing it, thanks!